# DynamoDB what is the efficient way to copy items of hash A to hash B?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have multiple data entires in Hash A, each entry has its own range key.
And I want to copy all of them to Hash B, their range can be same or any new value.

What is the fast way to do it? any built in way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about existing data there isn't really much you can do to make it faster/more efficient. You're going to have to do a scan of the data and write the new records. You can do this with a lambda, combined with step functions of the data is big enough that it won't complete in 15 minutes.

If you are talking about duplicating the data as it is added to the table you can use DynamoDB streams and add the duplicated record after the record is added.